# media preview for ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, media, preview

i want to preview media directly from url for example if i give it video display video preview if i give it image show it if i give it pdf show file preview and when press on it show the file content and so on

our media will be (images, videos, audios, pdfs, xlsx, docx)

so please if you have any information about aby framework or plugin please five me details

i have trying LPLinkView but it is showing metadata i dont want to show it but there is no options to hide metadata view

so please if you have any idea for that tell me please

looking forward for your help guys

thanks

Comment: Please share some code and tests so it would be easier to help you

Comment: i dont have code i want suggestions